# Sum numbers return from a php function

Tags: php

I have created 3 function to calculate revenue, manpower cost and other charges. But when I try to get net income($ni) my code return zero though the my variable has a value See the code below;

```
$revenue = revenue($project, $period);
$manpowerCost = manpowerCost($project, $period);
$otherCharges = otherCharges($project, $period);

$ni = $revenue - $manpowerCost - $otherCharges;
```

What is wrong with my code here?

Thanks

Comment: print and check if every value is being fetched correctly or not i.e. $revenue, $manpowerCost, $otherCharges

Comment: try to `echo  "$revenue - $manpowerCost - $otherCharges";` to see what are variable values

Comment: What values do `$revenue`, `$manpowerCost` and `$otherCharges` have?

Comment: Either your functions are erroneous or the costs by chance result in 0 net income.

Comment: what are values those functions returns?

Comment: [Debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `intval`  or `floatval` for each number for example

```
$ni = intval($revenue) - intval($manpowerCost) - intval($otherCharges);
```

or

```
 $ni = floatval($revenue) - floatval($manpowerCost) - floatval($otherCharges);
```

you will get your answer.

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer, if you don't mind plz upvote for this answer, so other also use this without hesitation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your functions return, you could try

```
$revenue = floatval(revenue($project, $period));
$manpowerCost = floatval(manpowerCost($project, $period));
$otherCharges = floatval(otherCharges($project, $period));

$ni = $revenue - $manpowerCost - $otherCharges;
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php for further details.